# Response.AddHeader seems undo simple code to set the text property of a textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, autopostback

OBJECTIVE: I am creating an aspx form that has basically a textbox and a button on it. If the user clicks the button I want to (1) fill in the textbox with the current date and (2) create/stream a pdf to the user to open/save the file.

PROBLEM: When I create/stream the pdf the textbox doesn't show my change. When stepping thru the code I see that the DateCompleted.Text does indeed change, but when I get to class that contains the PDF code the textbox reverts back. No errors of any type are trigged.

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
DateCompleted.Text = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", DateTime.Now) ' This works!

' more code.... DateCompleted.Text retains the correct value..... 

----- Enters the PDF class...

HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear() ' DateCompleted.Text is still correct**
HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "" ' DateCompleted.Text is still correct**
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", _
    Convert.ToString("attachment; filename=") & attachmentFilename) _ 
       ' DateCompleted.Text is NOT correct (restores previous value)**
```

So in the above example when I do the Response.AddHeader I noticed that the text property reverts back.

QUESTION: Any idea why this is happening? I have tried to research postback and issues related to the response object but haven't been able to find a solution yet. Any assistance would be appreciated! If you need anything clarified please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, you're still dealing with the HTTP protocol, which is entirely concerned with requests and responses.

> [Always two there are; no more, no less: a request, and a response](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7SjW0vFCiI)

Whenever someone clicks your button, they send a request to your server, and you must create a response. The problem is that you can only send one response to the request. Either you send an html document response with an updated textbox (and if you didn't know already, this is what happens: the entire html document is recreated and sent from your server and then re-loaded by the browser), or you send a pdf attachment response. You can't do both at the same time.

What you could do is update the textbox via javascript before submitting the request for the pdf attachment, or you could send a request for the updated textbox, and include javascript in the response to send an additional request asking for the pdf.